# Text selection handles always visible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, webview, textselection

I’m developing an application that includes a Webview. After a user selects text in the Webview a panel slides up and expands on top of the Webview and can hide the selected text. In this situation the text selection handles are popping up through the panel. this behaviour is not desired and distracting for the users.

I don’t want the selection input to go away after the panel shows up. Just don’t want the handles to be visible through the panel.

Couldn’t find a good solution or work around for this problem.

Any ideas?
Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

**I have Also Got This Type Of Error Here  is The Solution **

Certainly! Here's an example of how you can achieve the desired behavior in an Android application using a WebView and a sliding panel. You'll need to create an Android project and modify the following components:

**XML Layout (activity_main.xml):**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#333"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <!-- Sliding Panel Content -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Sliding Panel Content"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code (MainActivity.java):**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView webView;
private RelativeLayout panel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    panel = findViewById(R.id.panel);

    // Load a webpage in the WebView
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
            // Hide the panel if the scale changes (e.g., when the user zooms in/out)
            panel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    // When the WebView is long-pressed (text is selected), show the panel
    webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Show the sliding panel
            panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // When the panel is clicked, hide it
    panel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            panel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Make sure you have the necessary permissions and dependencies set up in your AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle files.

This example sets up a WebView and a sliding panel in an Android layout. When the user long-presses on the WebView (selects text), the panel becomes visible. When the panel is clicked, it hides again. Additionally, if the user zooms in/out on the WebView, the panel is automatically hidden. You can customize the behavior and appearance further according to your needs

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't solve the issue of the text selection handles. They still show up on top of the panel.

Comment: please try this link **[check](https://medium.com/@crosscountrybrasil/android-sliding-up-panel-with-bottomsheetbehaviour-6a8584040519)**